# How to pull data from a MySQL column and put it into a single array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Basically, this is what I currently use in an included file:

```
    $sites[0]['url'] = "http://example0.com";
    $sites[1]['url'] = "http://example1.com";
    $sites[2]['url'] = "http://example2.com";
    $sites[3]['url'] = "http://example3.com";
    $sites[4]['url'] = "http://example4.com";
    $sites[5]['url'] = "http://example5.com";
```

And so I output it like so:

```
foreach($sites as $s)
```

But I want to make it easier to manage via a MySQL database. So my question is, how can I make it automatically add additional "$sites[x]['url'] = "http://examplex.com";" and output it appropriately from my MySQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this:

```
$newSites = array_map('pick_attribute', $sites, 'url');

function pick_attributes($val, $prop) {
  return $val[$prop];
}
```

or a simple loop:

```
$newSites = array();
foreach ($sites as $v) {
  $newSites[] = $v['url'];
}
```